# Enabling wayland display server in CentOS stream9 automotive sig emulated by QEMU

Tags: centos, qemu

I am following [customizing_build](https://sigs.centos.org/automotive/building/customize_template/)

I am trying to build the image with wayland display server. However I am not able to get the display.
Running the built image using qemu-aarch64.
Running using:
qemu-system-aarch64 <imagename.qcow2> -device virtio-gpu-pci -display sdl, show-cursor=on -vga none -d guest_errors -device qemu-xhci -device usb-kbd -device usb-tablet